# Sorting results and determining joint positions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table that lists thousands of students with their score in an exam.

e.g.

```
name    score
andy    50
brian   56
chris   65
david   56
eddie   71
fred    50
greg    40
```

I am looking to run a query to give me the list of students ordered by score (easy) but also their position within the class. I need to consider joint positions.

For example, the student with the highest score has position 1, if the two best students have the same score then they both have position 1 and then the next best performing student should have position 3

Here is how I'd like the data listed earlier to be displayed:

```
name    score   position
eddie   71      1
chris   65      2
brian   56      3
david   56      3
andy    50      5    
fred    50      5
greg    40      7
```

How can I adapt this query to include the accurate position?

```
select name, score, '?' as position from students order by score
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `rank()`:

```
select s.*, rank() over (order by score desc) as position
from students;
```

This is available starting in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Great - I'll give this a go straight away. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

use this query if you are working with MSSQL2019

```sql
    SELECT
        name,
        score,
        RANK () OVER ( 
            ORDER BY score DESC
        ) position 
    FROM
        score
```

```
name    score   position
b        75        1
a        70        2
c        65        3
d        50        4
e        50        4
f        40        6
```